# Get greatest key in dictionary but lower than a variable

Tags: python

Given a dictionary and a variable like this:

```
dic = {0 : 'some', 10 : 'values', 20 : 'whatever'}
var = 14
```

I want to get the value from the dictionary where the key is the greatest but lower or equal to the variable. I don't know if that's clear but in this case I am looking for `10`.

I've come up with this function but I wanted to know if there is an easier way to do it as I am pretty new to python.

```
def get_greatest_key(dic, var):
    # if the key exists no need to search
    if var in dic:
        return dic[var]
    else:
        # create a list with all the keys sorted in reverse 
        l = sorted(dic, key=dic.get)
        i = 0
        while i < len(l):
            # parse the list
            if l[i] <= var:
                return dic[l[i]]
            i += 1
        # by default we return the last element in the dictionary
        return dic[l[len(l) - 1]]
```

Comment: If you need to do this a lot, a dict is probably the wrong data structure. I'd suggest a balanced BST except that I don't know of a good existing implementation for Python.

Comment: I suggest using [an AVL tree](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) instead. That, or sort the dictionary by key, and use a binary search.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want the maximum key which is less than or equal to `var`, then you can pass a generator expression to the `max` function:

```
>>> dic = {0 : 'some', 10 : 'values', 20 : 'whatever'}
>>> var = 14
>>> max(k for k in dic if k <= var)
10
```

with corresponding value

```
>>> dic[max(k for k in dic if k <= var)]
'values'
```

You can decide what to do with the `ValueError` thrown if the argument to `max` is empty as you see fit.

Comment: That's what I love about python, you can do awesome things in one line. Sadly I don't know it enough to find them. Works perfectly thanks! I'll accept the answer as soon as I can.